# Android NFC-HCE HostApduService not getting called when phone is unlocked

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, hce

I'm developing an Android application that must interact with a custom device through NFC. Android app acts as an emulated card (HCE) while the device plays the reader role.

Everything works when the phone is locked (screen on), but the HostApduService is not getting called when phone is unlocked.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce"
        android:required="false" />
...

        <service
            android:name=".communication.nfc.NfcService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
        </service>
```

apduservice.xml

```xml
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/nfcServiceDescription"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
    <aid-group
        android:category="other"
        android:description="@string/nfcServiceApertura">
        <aid-filter android:name="F70FC6AAAAAAA" />
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
```

Service

```
class NfcService : HostApduService() {

    override fun processCommandApdu(commandApdu: ByteArray, extras: Bundle?): ByteArray {
        val text = "processCommandApdu: " + commandApdu.asHexString()
        log(text)
    }

    override fun onDeactivated(reason: Int) {
        val text = "onDeactivated: $reason"
        log(text)
    }

    private fun log(mensaje: String) {
        Log.i(TAG, mensaje)
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "APDU"
    }
}
```

`NfcService.processCommandApdu` is getting called when the phone screen is locked and on, but it's not called when the phone is unlocked. I want it works in both states (locked and unlocked)

Comment: That's very very weird and this behavior shouldn't ever happen. It's more likely in the other way around though. Is it happening with every mobile?

Comment: Hi @GoRoS! Unfortunately, I only have two devices to test it and that was happening in both of them. Due to a change of priorities, I left it away since then.

Comment: my service is never get called ..